# Optimistic "locking" with Django transactions

Tags: python, django, locking, atomic

I have a function `fn()` that needs to atomically do some database work that relies on some set of data not changing during its execution (true most of the time).

What is the correct way to implement this in Django? Basically I'd like to do something like this:

```
def ensure_fn_runs_successfully():
  # While commit unsuccessful, keep trying
  while not fn():
    pass

@transaction.atomic
def fn():
  data = read_data_that_must_not_change()

  ... do some operations with the data and perform database operations ...

  # Assume it returns true if commit was successful, otherwise false
  return commit_only_if_the_data_actually_didnt_change()
```

`@transaction.atomic` takes care of part of the problem (database should only ever see the state before `fn` runs or after `fn` runs successfully), but I'm not sure if there exists a good primitive to do the `commit_only_if_the_data_actually_didnt_change`, and retrying the operation if it fails.

To verify the data didn't change, it would be enough to just check the count of items returned for a query is the same as it was at the beginning of the function; however, I don't know if there are any primitives that let you make the check and commit decision at the same time / without race condition.

Comment: Providing a minimal, complete and verifiable example will really help us provide a complete answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a transaction block, the only thing that can change the data that you are reading are other operations **within that same transaction block**.  So as long as `fn()` does not make any changes to `data`, you are guaranteed that the data will not change unless `fn()` changes it.  That is the problem that transactions are meant to solve.

If `data` can change within the confines of `fn()` just keep track of the places where it changes or keep track of the final result.

```
@transaction.atomic
def fn():
  data = read_data_that_must_not_change()
  original_data = copy.copy(data)
  ... do some operations with the data and perform database operations ...

  # Assume it returns true if commit was successful, otherwise false
  if data != original_data:
    raise Exception('Oh no!  Data changed!') 
    # raising in exception is how you prevent transaction.atomic
    # from committing
  return commit_only_if_the_data_actually_didnt_change()
```

And then handle the exception in you while loop like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        fn()
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(10) # ten second cool off
        pass
```

Comment: Yes it will work.  If the change to `item_set` that you are worried about is a change in the database, then the transaction makes any changes to `item_set` outside of the transaction impossible to execute simultaneously.  Either the changes to item_set will happen completely before the transaction block or completely after the transaction block.  ACID and all that.

Comment: Here’s a good primer on ACID and transactions as it seems that is what you are missing:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190612(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I think this statement of yours could only apply to _serializable_ transactions, but clarifying that data can be changed, only that our transaction could be failed by the db engine:

>If you are in a transaction block, the only thing that can change the data that you are reading are other operations within that same transaction block.

In lower levels of isolation (_read commited_, for example) our transaction block may experience _nonrepeatable reads_ and _phantom reads_ because of changes coming from outside of it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/transaction-iso.html

Comment: Also worth noting that pretty much no database does serializable isolation level by default, for performance reasons. E.g. Django's default for PostgreSQL is read committed.